# Naive Bayes Sentiment Analysis of Facebook Post

Tags: facebook, hadoop, sentiment-analysis, restfb, naivebayes

Could any of you help me with the following issue?

My goal is to make a sentiment analysis of the comments of a post to see if the feedback is positive or negative.

To do it, i have the following code of RestFB JAVA API:

```
Comments commentsPolarity; 
commentsPolarity = post.getComments();

                        if (commentsPolarity != null){
                            polarity = bayes.classify(Arrays.asList(commentsPolarity.toString())).getCategory();

                            ((BayesClassifier<String, String>) bayes).classifyDetailed(Arrays.asList(commentsPolarity.toString()));
                        }
```

My problem is that every analysis come back as negative, so I check what is in "commentsPolarity" variable and found out that it contains things like:

> "Comments[data=[Comment[attachment=null canRemove=true comments=null
>   createdTime=Fri Jun 05 12:21:32 BRT 2015
>   from=CategorizedFacebookType[category=Artist id=1440092102975875
>   metadata=null name=Luis Henrique type=null]
>   id=10153129969287326_10153133899852326 isHidden=null likeCount=0
>   likes=null **message**=Sou modelo e gostaria de mostrar meu trabalho,
>   consultem meu catálogo! metadata=null object=null parent=null
>   type=null userLikes=false canComment=false canHide=false]]
>   totalCount=4]"

I believe that if I can get only the **message**, my problem will be solved.

I'd tried to use `post.getComments().getData();` but then my Flume source stops 
create the final file with the data extracted.

So, could anybody give some clue of what to do?

Answer (score 0):

The object commentsPolarity has an array called data which contains the individual comments. Each of these comments has a message property. You need to iterate over something like  `commentsPolarity.getData();`   and extract the message from there.
Take this only as a guess because I have no idea how you initialized the  `post`  variable.

Comment: I posted just a piece of the code, because it is the only part that don't work rsrs. So, if I understood correctly, I need to do 'commentsPolarity.getData();' after I fill it with .getComments?

Comment: Yep. Something like:
`List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();`
`for (Comment comment: commentsPolarity.getData()){`
`list.add(comment.getMessage());`
`}`

Comment: I tried to do it, but for some reason FOR won't loop. It gives me only the first Comment